# List packages by section

Tags: apt, dpkg, apt-cache

I can run these commands to show the "Section" of certain packages

```
$ apt-cache show bash | grep Section
Section: shells

$ apt-cache show procps | grep Section
Section: admin
```

I would like a command to list all packages in a certain section. Here is what I
have tried

```
$ dpkg --list shells
dpkg-query: no packages found matching shells
```